# Is there a more efficient way of multiplying polynomials?

Tags: java, polynomial-math

Here is my method for multiplying two polynomials of the form `an*x^n + an-1*x^n-1 + ... + a1*x + a0`. Each `Term` object has two fields: `double coefficient` and `int power`. `Polynomial` represents a polynomial by storing the terms in an `ArrayList<Term>`. This current implementation of multiply is O(n^2). Any ideas or hints on how to make it faster?

```
public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial P2) {
    PolynomialImp result = new PolynomialImp();
    for (Term currentThisTerm : this.terms)
    {
        for (Term currentP2Term : ((PolynomialImp) P2).terms)
        {
            result.addTerm(new TermImp(currentThisTerm.getCoefficient()*currentP2Term.getCoefficient(), currentThisTerm.getExponent() + currentP2Term.getExponent()));
        }
    }
    //Sort polynomial in decreasing exponent order
    return result.sort();
}
```

Below is the addTerm method if needed:

```
private void addTerm(Term nextTerm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.terms.size(); i++)
    {
        if (this.terms.get(i).getExponent() == nextTerm.getExponent())
        {
            //Add the coefficients if the current term has the same exponent as a term that is already in the polynomial.
            //This preserves the sorting of the polynomial except during multiply.
            this.terms.set(i, new TermImp(this.terms.get(i).getCoefficient() + nextTerm.getCoefficient(), this.terms.get(i).getExponent()));
            return;
        }
    }
    //Avoid adding zeros to the polynomial.
    if (nextTerm.getCoefficient() != 0)
        this.terms.add(nextTerm);
}
```

Comment: I would use arrays of `double[]` with the co-efficient for each power.  This would still be O(n^2) to perform a multiplication. Are you sure you need it to be faster?

Comment: I don't need it to be faster, but I figured I might try for learns and giggles.

Comment: Polynomial Multiplication is O(n^2) unless you use FFT

Comment: The multiplication is a minimum of O(n^2), but your implementation is - due to the inner loop in addTerm() - approaching O(n^3) as worst case.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, the time used for determining the resulting polynomial should be fairly small as compared to evaluating the polynomial (assuming you are evaluating more than once). So you might also learn something worthwhile looking at Horner's method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), if you don't already know about it yet.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I might implement this functionality

```
public class Polynomial {
    private final double[] coeff;

    public Polynomial(double... coeff) {
        this.coeff = coeff;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(coeff);
    }

    public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial polynomial) {
        int totalLength = coeff.length + polynomial.coeff.length - 1;
        double[] result = new double[totalLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < coeff.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < polynomial.coeff.length; j++) {
                result[i + j] += coeff[i] * polynomial.coeff[j];
            }
        return new Polynomial(result);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(p1 + "^2 =" + p1.multiply(p1));
        Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial(3, -1, -1);
        System.out.println(p1 + "*" + p2 + "=" + p1.multiply(p2));
    }
}
```

prints

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]^2 =[1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 12.0, 9.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]*[3.0, -1.0, -1.0]=[3.0, 5.0, 6.0, -5.0, -3.0]
```

Comment: I know this is long after the answer was posted, but I can confirm that this works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what's making this algorithm slow is creating n^2 TermImp objects. In C++ this shouldn't be a problem because you would create the object on the stack and pass by value. My understanding is that in Java you don't have this option: you have to accept the overhead of creating an object and then pass by reference.

It seems inefficient that you're creating a new object every time you multiply a term. Couldn't you just eliminate it?

You could consider changing the addTerm method to accept a coefficient and an exponent as double/int arguments.

The algorithm will still be O(n^2) for large n but it should still speed up a lot.

The other thing you could consider would be using a for loop rather than iterators because iterators also involves creating new objects ... although O(n) so not so critical.

Answer (score 0):

You have one major inefficiency:  You store the terms in what appears to be an unordered list.  You should modify your code so that terms.get(n) returns the term with x^n.  Then you would not need to search through the terms variable in your addTerm method.

To do this, you would have to update all the code that modifies terms to keep terms ordered.

The multiply method itself looks efficient, I do not think it can be optimized much more.